# One of my images is not affected by opacity in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, opacity

One of the two arrows I have, and I'm not pointing fingers (its id="darrow") does not see to be affected by my opacity: 0.7; property in my CSS.  Can anyone see what's wrong?  It worked fine before I added the second arrow and the animation.  The other arrow seems to work flawlessly however.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/stills/uarrow.png" id="uarrow">
<img src="images/stills/darrow.png" id="darrow"> <!--Problem arrow-->
<div id="footer">
<p id="fpara">Site/logo design by Zachary Ledyard.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#darrow
{
    bottom: 20px;
}

#uarrow
{
    bottom: -40px;
}

#darrow, #uarrow
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 18px;
    height: 14px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 11;
}

#darrow, #uarrow:hover
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#footer
{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    z-index: 6;
    background-color: rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.7)
}
```

JQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#darrow").click(function(){
    $("#footer").animate({"top": "+=100px"}, "slow");
    $("#uarrow").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "slow");
    $("#darrow").animate({"top": "+=100px"}, "slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#uarrow").click(function(){
    $("#footer").animate({"top": "-=100px"}, "slow");
    $("#uarrow").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    $("#darrow").animate({"top": "-=100px"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant this to be `#darrow:hover`. You are overwriting the original opacity.

You need:

```
#darrow:hover, #uarrow:hover
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

and you have:

```
#darrow, #uarrow:hover
{
    /* this is replacing the previous opacity of 0.7 for #darrow */
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```